# Some specific Architectural or Design Patterns?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, jakarta-ee, design-patterns

Please do not close the question marking it as a dup before reading entirely my set of specific queries, as i am sincerely trying to connect few dots here...

1. Is MVC, an architectural or a design pattern? Likewise, any MV*?
2. Are Design Patterns, platform or programming language dependent?,
   because recently while learning, i have read full-lengh articles and blog 
   posts which mention the languages they are used in.

   e.g. Core JAVA, JavaScript & Enterprise JAVA etc.. Does it mean we can't 
   implement 1 pattern in the other language? Is it like few Design patterns 
   are only for JavaScript front-end, while others only for Core & Enterprise 
   JAVA (Web apps specially) backend?

   We also know already that MVC can be achieved at both, front & back ends 
   e.g. using Angular & Spring frameworks, respectively...
3. Also, can Pub/Sub & Observer Patterns only be implemented in
   JavaScript? How is Event-bus driven architecture different from
   them? Since we already know that Node.JS internally uses Pub/Sub &
   also is Event-bus driven...
4. Also, do we already have in-built programming constructs in both
   JAVA & JavaScript, which implement such patterns or allow us to use
   them to achieve those patterns?
5. Also, what are some of the most important or significant & must-know Architectural &/or Design Patterns for enhancing my career

Comment: This is a question for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ , while SO is for code problems. The question is too broad and tries to address many things at once 1. MVC is architectural but you can call it design pattern if you use it as such, e.g. locally. 2. Some design patterns may be specific or impractical with some langs. 3. No, they aren't specific to JS, you could figure this out by googling 4. We possibly do 5. Start with Gang of Four's patterns

Comment: @estus thanks a ton for your direction, short 1 line answers & suggestions. Answers most of my queries very easily...